# Stop jQuery ajax refresh after X seconds

Tags: jquery, ajax, refresh, setinterval

I use jQuery ajax to refresh a div every 2 seconds.

How to stop this refresh after 60 seconds (example, if user is inactive) ?

```
setInterval(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "feeds.php",
    cache: false
  }).done(function( html ) {
  $('#feeds').replaceWith('<div id="feeds">'+html+'</div>');
   });
}, 2000);
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assign the setInterval handle to a variable, which you will use to clear it after 60 seconds.

```
var interval = setInterval(function(){ ... }, 2000);

// start a 60 second timer
setTimeout(function(){ window.clearInterval(interval); }, 60000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not so hard.

```
var myInterval = setInterval(function(){},2000);
setTimeout(function() { clearInterval( myInterval ); }
```

I'm not sure if this has leaks.

Answer (score 0):

```
//store the ajax call into a variable
var chr =  $.ajax({ .....}

//use setTimeout to invoke its abort() method after 1000 ms (1 second)
setTimeout(function(){
  chr.abort()
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Could you add an explanation as to why this solves it

Comment: setTimeout function will abort the ajax call after "1000"mseconds , which is 1minute or 60 second duration